# effect of normalizing on mel-spectrogram

Tags: speech, spectrogram

what is the effect of normalizing (using mean and std of each channel) on the mel-spectrogram?
this is a image of [mel-spectrogram with 20 mel filters and 206 frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBZS9.png) and this is a [normalized mel-spectrogram with same shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2C1D.png). we see that some properties appeared after normalizing the mel-spectrogram.
does it remove some properties from the original mel-spectrogram?